# Python Render Specific Frames

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I'm new to blender scripting and with the api change in 2.56 I'm having difficulty finding relevant information. I'm trying to render 8 non-consecutive single frames to pngs. They are the same scene and camera, I'm just trying to get different angles of an object for creating sprites for a game. I found [this](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?87757-PYTHON-sequentially-rendering-multiple-frame-batches) tutorial but it's out of date.

I hate to ask for code because it's almost going to be the whole script, but it would be apreciated. I would be just as happy with a some direction on getting started though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try setting the frame and then rendering it.

- [`bpy.ops.render.render()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.ops.render.html?#bpy.ops.render.render) is an operator which renders the current scene.
- [`bpy.context.scene.frame_set()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=frame_set#bpy.types.Scene.frame_set) is an operator which sets the scene frame.

Here is a simple example:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
fp = scene.render.filepath # get existing output path
scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG' # set output format to .png

frames = 5, 9, 17

for frame_nr in frames:

    # set current frame to frame 5
    scene.frame_set(frame_nr)

    # set output path so render won't get overwritten
    scene.render.filepath = fp + str(frame_nr)
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True) # render still

# restore the filepath
scene.render.filepath = fp
```

Comment: I always forget how - nice to be able to find that *perfect, concise answer!*