# Render different frames

Tags: rendering

How can I create a automatic render setup, for example, I need to render with the same settings to an mp4, from the 001 to 10 one file, than from the 011 to 021 another and a few others.

Comment: Like a batch rendering but straight from blender.

Comment: Do you need to change video format between the files or would you just end up with multiple MP4 files?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17839/599

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a quick script to render out separate frame ranges of the animation. The script assumes you've set an output folder correctly as well as setting the video format settings as you want them.

```
import bpy
import os

frameList = [
    [1,50],
    [51,100],
    [101,150]
    ]

scn = bpy.context.scene

for fr in frameList:

    scn.frame_start = int(fr[0])
    scn.frame_end = int(fr[1])
    bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
```

Comment: That's weird, didn't happen to me with my test file. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Is your scene really memory intensive?  Could Blender be reloading all the scene assets for each render without releasing the memory for the previous render?

Comment: With your current settings, can you manually render a file with no issues?