# Multi-scene rendering

Tags: rendering

I am very new to Blender and have been trying to figure out a way to render and save a sequence of scenes without having to manually render one after another. Each scene has a different light pattern projected onto chessboard image plane as part of a structured light calibration sequence. I have directly copied the scene 42 times, incrementally changing the light for each scene. I just want to render and save each scene automatically without having to navigate to each scene an re-render. I've exhaustively searched solutions without any success and feel this should be a very simple task.
Is there not a way that Blender can queue scenes for rendering? I don't care how long it will take, I just don't want to manually do this for each scene.   Here are some images from the sequence for context:
Light Sequence 1:
[image]
.
.
.

Light Sequence 10
[image]

All the way to Light Sequence 42

Comment: this question was asked a lot here...just search here for "automatic render". e.g. : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34303/render-different-frames using this answer you could extend by looping over your scenes-> ready

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that this isn't a proper answer but will help a lot when beginning in blender and isn't a comment because there are useful images.

Im not sure how to do this but id reccomend not copying the same object 42 times, just setup view layers,

To do this select the objects you want to isolate in each renders and then if you press m you get the option to move it to a different layer, create a new layer and put it there.
Once you've done that you can then press the new view layer button in the top bar, and make sure you copy settings.

[image: Step by step on how to move to new layers and create view layers]

Once you have created the new view layer you can change the visibility for different objects in different layers, make sure you are in the correct view layer and then right click the layer that you want to change and hover over the view layer button there and then finally press disable/enable for this layer. Then in the compositor you can either use an output node to output every image or just use the built in compositor and change the view layer.

Hope this is helpful, if u need any help just ask