# How can I specify filenames of animation renders as [SCENE NAME] + [FRAME] when rendering an image sequence?

Tags: rendering

I'm rendering out products from different angles. I set up keyframes to rotate the product to the desired angles, then I'm doing an image sequence animation render for each angle. Is there a way to specify the filenames to the scene name followed by either a custom name, or the frame number? Thank You!

Comment: Have you tagged the question with 'python' and 'scripting' because you are triggering the rendering by code?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/17840/30849) already explains how to render certain frames.

```
bpy.context.scene.name             ...   the scene's name
bpy.context.scene.frame_start      ...   the scene's starting frame
```

---

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
fp = scene.render.filepath # get existing output path

for frame_nr in range(scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end):

    # set current frame
    scene.frame_set(frame_nr)

    # set output path
    scene.render.filepath = "//render/" + scene.name + "_folder/" + scene.name + "_customName_" + '{0:03d}'.format(frame_nr)
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)    
 scene.render.filepath = fp
```

Refer to:

- [padding ints with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string)
- [the range function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265935/python-create-list-with-numbers-between-2-values)

Answer (score 0):

For what I needed, I just specified the file path names, starting with the product name and then it added the frame name to the end.